# soundprofing edm studio room

Tags: insulation, sound-proofing, curtain-rail

if i hang mass loaded vinyl like curtains around the room,will it soundproof the room do other neighbours will not complain when im doing music in strange hours?
what other options do i have for a rental apartment?

i know about this product [Producer's Choice](http://www.vocalboothtogo.com/acoustic-and-soundproofing-products-vocal-booths/acoustic-%28sound%29-blankets-for-sound-absorption---producers-choice/sound-blanket-producers-choice-with-grommets.-solid-black/8-25#ja-pathway)
but i don't know if it will soundproof the room

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/13212/20
http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/4534/20
http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/33371/20

Answer (score 0):

You're right that the sound blankets will do little if anything to soundproof the room. They mostly just serve to reduce echo.

Hanging MLV curtains on the walls will probably make a noticeable difference at higher frequencies, but won't do much to stop bass. You can get somewhat better results if the curtains are separated from the walls by a good distance (a few feet) but again it's still not going to do a lot to stop bass. You can add in a riser that isolates the sound from the floor, for a bigger improvement.

But your only truly effective option if you can't modify the existing construction is to build a room within a room, with its own isolated floor and ceiling.

Comment: thanks for the replay! i forgot the write that im not worried about the floor,my apt is in the first floor.what materials do you recommend using for the inner room? my room is small at it is,how will it effect the size?

Comment: Even if there isn't an apartment below you, the floor is still a concern because it can serve as a flanking path, letting sound travel to your neighbors under soundproofed walls.